# Install bumblebee on debian 9

Tags: debian, xorg, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

I'm trying to install bumblebee on my laptop but i've some problem after the installation.i'm still unable to run something with primusrun.

**primusrun glxgears -info**

```
/usr/bin/primusrun: riga 41: attenzione: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

**systemctl status bumblebeed**

```
● bumblebeed.service - Bumblebee C Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bumblebeed.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-12-09 03:22:16 CET; 13s ago
 Main PID: 1992 (bumblebeed)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bumblebeed.service
           └─1992 /usr/sbin/bumblebeed

dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480850] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480863] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480869] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) No drivers available.
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480872] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480875] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) no screens found(EE)
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480877] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480880] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for a
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480884] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480887] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
dic 09 03:22:27 msi bumblebeed[1992]: [ 1596.480889] [ERROR]X did not start properly
```

**xorg.conf.nvidia**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting may be needed in some platforms with more than one
#   nvidia card, which may confuse the proprietary driver (e.g.,
#   trying to take ownership of the wrong device). Also needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
   BusID "PCI:01:00:0"

#   Setting ProbeAllGpus to false prevents the new proprietary driver
#   instance spawned to try to control the integrated graphics card,
#   which is already being managed outside bumblebee.
#   This option doesn't hurt and it is required on platforms running
#   more than one nvidia graphics card with the proprietary driver.
#   (E.g. Macbook Pro pre-2010 with nVidia 9400M + 9600M GT).
#   If this option is not set, the new Xorg may blacken the screen and
#   render it unusable (unless you have some way to run killall Xorg).
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"

    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```

**bumblebee.conf**

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
# Xorg binary to run
XorgBinary=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/primus:/usr/lib32/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia:/usr/lib/nvidia
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia/nvidia,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

**dpkg -l | grep nvidia**

```
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                              3.2.1-14                                   amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
ii  glx-alternative-nvidia                        0.8.3~deb9u1                               amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  nvidia-alternative                            384.130-1                                  amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  nvidia-installer-cleanup                      20151021+4                                 amd64        cleanup after driver installation with the nvidia-installer
ii  nvidia-kernel-common                          20151021+4                                 amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-kernel-dkms                            384.130-1                                  amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module DKMS source
ii  nvidia-kernel-support                         384.130-1                                  amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-legacy-check                           384.130-1                                  amd64        check for NVIDIA GPUs requiring a legacy driver
ii  nvidia-modprobe                               384.111-2~deb9u1                           amd64        utility to load NVIDIA kernel modules and create device nodes
```

**dpkg -l | grep bumblebee**

```
ii  bumblebee                                     3.2.1-14                                   amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                              3.2.1-14                                   amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
```

Comment: See  [bumblebee needs configuration changes to work with nvidia-driver-390 and libglvnd0](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bumblebee/+bug/1758243).

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the nvidia module is not loaded

1. Run the following to check you have the module installed

   lsmod | grep nvidia
2. Blacklist nouveau in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` by adding the line

   blacklist nouveau

Comment: This is unclear. What is the user supposed to do if `lsmod | grep nvidia` shows that the nvidia module is loaded? What is the user supposed to do if the nvidia module is not loaded? Why?

Comment: The log file shows nvidia module is not loaded. So either its bumblebee config problem or nvidia driver installation . so I think if lsmod shows nvidia modules loaded then its bumblebee config problem. And he need to remove KernelDriver=nvidia-current    to only "nvidia"  and also need to add line Module = nvidia

Comment: Still, your answer could be clearer on the instructions to be completed.